# рестарт демона smbd без прерывания нагрузки на клиенте windows

Tags: samba, smb

Всем привет!
Такая проблема, есть сервер(кластер), на котором используется смб, сервер введен в домен AD, так как это кластер, иногда требуется выполнять рестарт службы smbd(reload не подойдет), но при этом если идет какое то копирование файла на клиенте(windows), то нагрузка прерывается(что логично), и после нажатия кнопки "Повторить", загрузка файла начинается с самого начала, можно ли сделать как то что бы нагрузка продолжала идти с того момента где прервалась, может нужно настроить клиента как то. клиент подключается как SMBv3 или SMBv2

сервер на ubuntu 18.04.
папка смб создана на зфс

smb.conf:

```
[global]
    workgroup = TEST247
    realm = test247.ru
    security = ads
    auth methods = winbind
    interfaces = 172.16.11.170/24 
    bind interfaces only = yes
    netbios name = SERVER
    encrypt passwords = true
    map to guest = Bad User
    max log size = 300
    dns proxy = no
    socket options = TCP_NODELAY
    domain master = no
    local master = no
    preferred master = no
    os level = 0
    domain logons = no
    load printers = no
    show add printer wizard = no
    log level = 0 vfs:2
    max log size = 0
    syslog = 0
    printcap name = /dev/null
    disable spoolss = yes
    name resolve order = lmhosts wins host bcast
    machine password timeout = 604800
    name cache timeout = 660
    idmap config TEST247 : backend = rid
    idmap config TEST247 : base_rid = 0
    idmap config TEST247 : range = 100000 - 200000
    idmap config * : range = 200001-300000
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    idmap cache time = 604800
    idmap negative cache time = 60
    winbind rpc only = yes
    winbind cache time = 120
    winbind enum groups = yes
    winbind enum users = yes
    winbind max domain connections = 10
    winbind use default domain = yes
    winbind refresh tickets = yes
    winbind reconnect delay = 15
    winbind request timeout = 25
    winbind separator = ^
    private dir = /var/lib/samba/private
    lock directory = /run/samba
    state directory = /var/lib/samba
    cache directory = /var/cache/samba
    pid directory = /run/samba
    log file = /var/log/samba/smb.%m
    include = /etc/samba/smb-res.conf
```

testparm:

```
testparm -s /etc/samba/smb.conf 

Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
WARNING: The "auth methods" option is deprecated
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_DOMAIN_MEMBER
```

конфиг шары:
smb-res.conf:

```
[test109_smb]
    comment = test109_smb share
    path = /config/pool/test109/smb
    browseable = yes
    writable = yes
    inherit acls = yes
    inherit owner = no
    inherit permissions = yes
    map acl inherit = yes
    nt acl support = yes
    create mask = 0777
    force create mode = 0777
    force directory mode = 0777
    store dos attributes = yes
    public = no
    admin users = 
    valid users =  
    write list = 
    read list = 
    invalid users = 
    vfs objects = acl_xattr    
    full_audit:prefix = %S|%u|%I
    full_audit:facility = local5
    full_audit:priority = notice
    full_audit:success = none
    full_audit:failure = none
    shadow: snapdir = .zfs/snapshot
    shadow: sort = desc
    shadow: localtime = yes
    shadow: format = shadow_%d.%m.%Y-%H:%M:%S
    worm: grace_period = 30
    cryptfile: method = grasshopper
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

много где писали что сам smb протокол да и многие виндовые службы копирования не поддерживают докачку, и нужно пользоваться какимито сторонними службами копирования, везде советуют KillCopy, я его установил и все вроде норм работает, докачка происходит